# Match text to nested array and return Id value

Tags: angular

I am trying to match text to values in a nested array. However the result that I need from the array is the roles ID. eg. I have text called HR Admin, now I want to search the object under the "roles" object and return the ID which is "4"

Here is my code

Array

```
{
  "genders": null,
  "races": null,
  "titles": null,
  "maritalStatus": null,
  "nationality": null,
  "identityTypes": null,
  "roles": {
    "1": "System Admin",
    "2": "Internal Account Manager",
    "3": "CAT Manager",
    "4": "HR Admin",
    "5": "HR Manager",
    "6": "HR Recruiter",
    "7": "Candidate",
    "8": "Operations administrator"
  },
  "companyTypes": null,
  "industries": null,
  "fileTypes": null
}
```

I am trying to filter but am not getting anywhere

```
const myFilter = (resp, num) => {
  const values = resp.filter(det => !!det.roles.find(l => l === num));

  return values.map(res => {
    res.roles = res.roles.filter(l => l === num);
    return res;
  });
};
```

Comment: roles is not an arrray but an object, you can transform it into array of string or array of object with property of id and property of job and then filter.

if you still want the data structure to stay the same in the myFilter convert the num into a string and return roles[num]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the index of the given value ("HR Admin") and get the key for that same index:

```js
const obj = {
    "genders": null,
    "races": null,
    "titles": null,
    "maritalStatus": null,
    "nationality": null,
    "identityTypes": null,
    "roles": {
        "1": "System Admin",
        "2": "Internal Account Manager",
        "3": "CAT Manager",
        "4": "HR Admin",
        "5": "HR Manager",
        "6": "HR Recruiter",
        "7": "Candidate",
        "8": "Operations administrator"
    },
    "companyTypes": null,
    "industries": null,
    "fileTypes": null
};

const search = 'HR Admin';
const index = Object.values(obj.roles).indexOf(search);
const result = Object.keys(obj.roles)[index];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Before you use this, make sure you check whether the index is actually `>-1`.